# User input to reference file doesn't work on Apache server

Tags: javascript, html, image, apache

I made a webpage that takes user input and appends it to a filepath to update an image on the page. The search bar/button works when I open the .html file as a plain file in Chrome, but when I copy the file to the Apache /www folder and open it through localhost, it doesn't work. I've already determined that it's not a JS problem, so could it be a permissions problem, or maybe that Apache doesn't update the page in the same way as when I open the file on its own? This is more a conceptual question than a syntax question, but I can upload the code if that would help.

The important parts:

```
<script>
function updatemap (){
   document.getElementById('floormap').src = "file://C:/wamp64/www/Floormaps/" 
   + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('textInput').value) + ".jpg";
    }
</script>

<script>
document.getElementById("textInput")
    .addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("searcher").click();
    }
});
</script>

<input id="textInput" type="text" 
    onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13)
        document.getElementById('searcher').click()">

<button id="searcher" onclick="updatemap()">Search</button>

<img id="floormap" src="" 
alt="Map" 
style="width:65%; height:65%;">
</img>
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a html/js problem to me but like a plain apache-setup problem. Double check that apache is running, which directory it serves, whether there are any lines in the access logs, ... Or just search for "_apache setup {YOUR_OS}_" to find respective tutorials to get it running properly

Comment: Yeah, I'll mark this solved. The problem was that I was trying to use an HTML form, but I should have been using a PHP form to get the user input with POST, etc. Also, I had the file saved as .html, when I should have saved it as .php.

Comment: Don't mark your post title as solved. If you've since found an answer, add it as an answer (not in your question).